# Facebook GRAPH api list videos from page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to list all videos from a Facebook Fan Page an i got some problems. I keep getting `Facebook SDK returned an error: You must provide an access token.`. I tried using the access token, but no use.

CODE :

```
use Facebook;
use Facebook\FacebookApp;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use FileUpload\FacebookFile;
use FileUpload\FacebookVideo;
use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken;

$expires = time() + 60 * 60 * 2;
$accessToken = new Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken('mytoken1234567890', $expires);
var_dump($accessToken);

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXX',
  'access_token' => "mytoken1234567890",
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);
$request = $fb->request('POST', '/uniladmag/videos');

try
{
    $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} 
catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
{
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e)
{
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

print_r($graphNode);
?>
```

OUTPUT :

```
object(Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken)#2 (2) {
  ["value":protected]=>
  string(17) "mytoken1234567890"
  ["expiresAt":protected]=>
  object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2017-02-14 18:20:13.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
}
Facebook SDK returned an error: You must provide an access token.
```

What solutions do i have? Do i miss something?

Thanks.

Comment: The initialization parameter to set the default access token is named `default_access_token`.

Comment: Try passing $accessToken to 'access_token' in your $fb initialization call instead of  "mytoken1234567890"

Also, since you are getting a list of videos and not uploading one, call GET in your request and not POST.

Comment: after adding `'default_access_token' => "mytoken1234567890",` i get `Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.`  ... do i need to login with `OAuth2` ?